# Como Impedir acesso com macros desabilitadas?

Tags: vba

Tenho um formulário de cadastro que aparece assim que abrimos a planilha. A lista de cadastro (nas sheets) fica invisível, podendo ser acessada apenas por senha ao clicar no botão "Banco de Dados".
Porém, quando uma pessoa vai acessá-la pela primeira vez na sua máquina, aparece o aviso do Excel para habilitar as macros, e o conteúdo da planilha (nas sheets) acaba sendo exposto ao usuário. Gostaria que aparecesse apenas uma sheet de aviso, com o objetivo de fazer abrir o formulário apenas se ele habilitar antes as macros. Já criei ela com as orientações e a deixei em VeryHidden, porém queria saber como seria o código para colocar em ThisWorkbook. Acho que seria em Workbook_BeforeClose.

Alguém saberia ajudar?

Comment: Olá colega, bem vindo ao SOPT. Este site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour], mas principalmente não deixe de ler [ask]. Sua pergunta não está totalmente clara. Parece que vc diz que o formulário é exibido mesmo se o usuário não habilitar as macros (o que eu acho improvável, já que sem macros habilitadas o código do formulário não executa). Sobre expor conteúdo das planilhas (sheets), não é só uma questão de colocar senha no arquivo Excel? Enfim, explique melhor o seu problema, ilustre com alguma imagem e, se possível, prepare um [mcve] pra ajudar no entendimento.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Luiz. Gostaria de poder colocar fotos, mas ainda não tenho essa permissão. O que quero dizer é que quando o usuário abre o arquivo, o conteúdo é exposto até ele habilitar as macros. Não quero que isto aconteça. Por isso criei uma planilha de aviso e quero que só ela seja exposta, enquanto as que contém os dados estão escondidas, quando ele abrir a planilha pela primeira vez. Há uma maneira de fazer isto por código. Este link ( está em inglês) explica a minha situação. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/EnableMacros.aspx. Estou tentando adaptar à minha realidade

Comment: Por nada, Granado. Bom, mesmo assim você poderia ter editado a pergunta para deixar mais claro alguns pontos, até mesmo colocar o link que você está tentando reproduzir.

Answer (score 0):

consegui!!!!

Meu código ficou assim:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

  'Passo 1: Declarando variáveis

  'Dim ws As Worksheet

  'Passo 2: Deixa visível a Sheet inicial

  'Sheets("Alerta").Visible = xlSheetVisible

  'Passo 3: Inicia looping em todas as worksheets

  'For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

  'Passo 4: Checa o nome de cada Worksheet

  'If ws.Name <> "Alerta" Then

  'Passo 5: Esconde a Sheet

  'ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden

  End If

  'Passo 6: Loop na próxima Worksheet

  'Next ws

  'Passo 7: Salva a planilha

  'ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  'Passo 1: Declarando variáveis

  'Dim ws As Worksheet

  'Passo 2: Inicia looping em todas as worksheets

  'For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

  'Passo 3: Mostra todas as Sheets

  'ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible

  'Passo 4: Loop na próxima Wworksheet

  'Next ws

  'Passo 5: Esconde todas as Sheets

  'Application.Visible = False

  'Passo 6: Mostra apenas o Formulário de Cadastro ao abrir a Workbook

  'FormulárioReserva.Show


End Sub
```

Obrigado pela atenção!!!!! :)

Comment: Que bom que você conseguiu resolver. Melhor ainda que se preocupou em responder você mesmo! :) Só dois detalhes: 1) o código está todo comentado. É bom deixar o código funcional, para que possa ser útil para outra pessoa no futuro. 2) Seria bom também explicar um pouco como ele funciona. No seu caso, a explicação está em comentários, então está mais ok. Mas talvez o entendimento fique mais claro quando vc melhorar um pouco a pergunta. Depois de fazer algumas dessas alterações, me avise que eu te dou o meu +1. :)